# Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n!\frac{z^{n}}{n^{n}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n!\frac{z^{n}}{n^{n}}$.

The textbook answer is $\mathit{e}$. I know how to find the radius of convergence if $n$ started at 0, but in this case, it starts at 1. Do I manipulate the series before doing any root/ratio tests? If so, do I manipulate the indices or do I manipulate the summand? Any advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: What's the difference between starting at $0$ or at $1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $1$, I suppose :)

Answer (score 2):

use the ratio test:

$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \frac{\left(n+1\right) n^n |z|}{\left(n+1\right)^{n+1}} = \frac{n^n}{\left(n+1\right)^n} |z| = \frac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n} |z| $

$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to e$ as $n \to \infty$, thus radius of convergence is $e$.

Comment: It's the best way to do it, but the typical "ratio test" for power series would not have a z. If it it's the ratio test for series, then it should be $|z|$.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, added $|z|$

Answer (score 1):

In the given power series the coefficients are $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$

Let $R$ be the radius of convergence. Now by root test, $\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n \to \infty} {a_n}^{1/n}= \lim_{n \to \infty} {(\frac{n!}{n^n})}^{1/n}$

Now in above plug in the Stirling's approximation : $n! $ ~ $(\frac{n}{e})^n \sqrt{2\pi n}$ to obtain that $R=e$

Comment: I think Stirling is a bit of an overkill in this case.

Comment: @Gary "There's no sense in being precise when you don't even know what you're talking about" - Von Neumann

Comment: The   exact formula is the  $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}$ (the limit doesn't always exist).

Answer (score 0):

Starting the series at $0$ gives an undefined first term, that is why I'm assuming that the series starts at $n=1$. Otherwise, try letting $z=1$ and use the ratio test on the series $$\sum \frac{n!}{n^n}.$$

Comment: What do you think is undefined about $0!\frac{z^0}{0^0}$?

Comment: How is it defined?

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to 0} n^{-0} = 1$$ while $$\lim_{n\to 0} 0^{-n} = \pm \infty.$$